# No puedo instalar paquetes usando "library" en Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

Tengo como objetivo extraer algunas visualizaciones de Rstudio (para una trabajo en un seminario, que debo entregar mañana y estoy contrarreloj, por eso recurro a este espacio)
He realizado todos los pasos que se solicitan, pero con dificultades para instalar paquetes:
Estoy en sistema operativo Windows 7

```
- Tengo lista en Zotero (para usar en el ejercicio)
- instalé R y Rstudio (4.3.0) (funcionando)
- En Rstudio, hice el setwd. Esta parte esta bien ingresada en la consola
luego library para install packages, escribí el código de todos los paquetes tal como dice en el temario y en la clase en línea, pero cuando doy "run" en la consola dice en forma permanente por ejemplo para el caso de library install.packages (tidyverse): Error: unexpected symbol in ¨library  install.packages"

También escribí más abajo el código de bibliosylo y de ggplot, etc.
```

Obviamente todas ellas dan error, porque supongo que al no quedar bien ingresado library, ya no conecta con el resto.
Pregunto:¿qué debería hacer o corroborar?

[image: Adjunto el salvapantalla del escritorio de Rstudio]

Comment: Quita `library` y solo usa `install.packages("tidyverse")`

Comment: Gracias René!, sí, ya lo había hecho anteriormente. Y no dio resultado. Voy a volver a hacerlo. He probado de diferentes maneras para ver si hay algún cambio.

Comment: Hola René!, aparentemente funciona, también volví a instalar los paquetes a través de la interfaz, y borré lo anterior y lo volví a hacer. Así que puedo decir que tu ayuda funcionó. Gracias!! Ahora estoy con otras dificultades de bibliostylo... voy a leer si hay referencias, sino volveré a generar una pregunta.